# Proper array(&$this) syntax with arguments

Tags: php, oop

Take the following code example:

```
<?php
    class A {

        public function aa() {
            $output = (array(&$this, 'ab'), $post_id);
            return $output;
        }

        public function ab( $post_id ) {
            //do stuff
        }

    }
?>
```

What's the correct way to call method ab that contains additional arguments like `$post_id`?

I know that the `$output` line doesn't work, but that's the line I'm stuck on.

Thanks.

Comment: From where do you get $post_id?

Comment: 1) [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) 2) There is no need for the `&` in `&$this`. All objects are implicitly passed by reference in PHP5.

Comment: So you're saying there's no need to call methods within classes with array(&$this) anymore, Dave?

I ask because I've used array(&$this) in my classes before w/o any problems (and I'm not a PHP expert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this way:

```
$output = $this->ab($post_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this . May be this will help.

```
<?php
class A {

    public function aa() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $output = call_user_func_array(array($this,'ab'),$args);
        // But this way the "ab" function have to be private
        // Or you can simply do $output = $this->ab($post_id)
        return $output;
    }

    public function ab( $post_id ) { 
        //do stuff
    }

}
$a = new A();
$a->aa(162);

?>
```